# Weird Network Problems

Tags: networking

I am having a weird Network problem for a while now: Almost no programs are using the available bandwidth I have except my speed test.

I have connection problems on pretty much every game and website on my computer although my speed test is showing me that my download speed is 96Mbps which would be about 11MB/s

I am only downloading with about 300KB/s and my Taskmanagaer is showing me that the only time my network is at full capacity is while I am doing a speed test else it is not going over 1%.

it does not seem to be a problem with the router because no one else in my house has this problem.

how can I fix it and why isn't the rest of my Pc(windows 10 btw) using the available internet.

sorry for my bad formulation of this problem it is my first time on a site like this!

Comment: Have you tested against different download sources (Speedtest.net lets you choose the server -- make sure to test against something that _doesn't_ belong to your ISP, as well as something that does)? Are you using any VPN service? (Does the situation change if you enable or disable the VPN?) Do you see anything unusual in a [packet capture](https://www.wireshark.org/) -- such as lots of retransmissions, or lots of IP packets having the 'ToS: CE' flag?

Comment: "it does not seem to be a problem with the router because no one else in my house has this problem." => It is something related to your computer. Using WiFi => check settings, distance to AP, swap channel used (use e.g. Wifi Analyzer on Google Play to see the info). If nothing there helps then verify that your hardware is fault free, replace if not...

Answer (score 0):

Download speeds are not solely dependent on *your* network's capacity. There can also be bottlenecks elsewhere in the connection between your PC and the host sending the file.

For example, if you want to download a file from a server somewhere but that machine is only able to transmit at 10 Mbps, assuming nothing else in between has a slower max speed you would only receive it at 10 Mbps.

Comment: first of all thanks for the answer and second this problem seems to affect all of my programs and all of my games I have this problem in move or die, in overwatch, and on Minecraft servers. the problem isn't directly that they aren't using my whole bandwidth because they don't need to but the problem rather is that they are still using way less than they have too creating lag.

Comment: When you view the network connection, is it toggled to be a metered connection? That will enable some data-saving measures which may cause symptoms like this.